# Gradlew clean build is failed for spring boot java app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have downloaded Gradle 4.1 and kept `GRADLE_HOME` env setting and tried to `gradlew clean build`.

It is failing with the following exception

```
A problem occurred configuring root project '_app_'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.pitest:pitest-command-line:1.1.10.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.pitest:pitest-command-line:1.1.10.
         > Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy
      > Could not resolve org.pitest:pitest-command-line:1.1.10.
         > Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy
   > Could not resolve info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.1.10.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.1.10.
         > Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy
      > Could not resolve info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.1.10.
         > Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE.
         > Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE.
         > Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy
```

When I ran the same in debug mode I could see this

```
14:18:09.950 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
14:18:10.013 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@de542e
14:18:10.013 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 10: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
14:18:10.013 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project '_app_'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=7464, address=[093d98c5-c3fb-4d52-8769-f354b16ed886 port:59558, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1504514729826, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=1fa87ce9-9184-48a6-9489-499fe27fffa0,javaHome=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131,daemonRegistryDir=D:\Users\RMuthu\.gradle\daemon,pid=7464,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
14:18:10.013 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
14:18:10.013 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.pitest:pitest-command-line:1.1.10.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMet
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:13
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:11
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:89
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy
```

Comment: Which Gradle version you download and which GRADLE_HOME you set is nearly without meaning if you use the Gradle wrapper (`gradlew`). One big pro of the Gradle Wrapper is, that you do not need to have Gradle installed, just Java. The wrapper automatically downloads and uses the Gradle version the build is designed for and works with properly. So your locally installed Gradle version is ignored. Which Gradle version is defined in `<rootProject>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`? Can you show the full build output with `-s`? Your debug output seems to be cropped before or after relevance.

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip

Comment: Well yes, then it is using 4.1. But the latter question still stands. :-)

Comment: Exception stack trace indicates the model version resolve exception org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.pitest:pitest-command-line:1.1.10.

Comment: This is a consecutive error. Provide the full log, or you cannot be helped.

Comment: I think there is no issue with the project as it working in other system..What could be the possible reason

Comment: One last try to say it with clear words, then I ignore this post: Provide the full log, or you cannot be helped.

Comment: please find this link let me know if you are able access or not https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3648324c5e140630ce99c97d8119159e

Comment: Exception stack https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea29fc4881e814413061e13b73b35cb4

Comment: I can access the links, but I think the root cause is still missing. Can you post the full log when running with `-s` and `-d` please? The first link does not contain any stracktraces at all, the second link only contains a cropped log. Maybe also add `-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false` to make sure there are no errors swallowed by the daemon. Shouldn't happen, but who knows.

Comment: Please find new link command used gradlew clean build -s -d -stacktrace -info -debug -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f7a9fa94ef057ade0e8c3237151f13d8

Comment: Hi I re-installed java and the problem is solved :)

Comment: Ah, strange, good that you solved it. Then please delete your question or answer it yourself. Btw. `-s` and `--stacktrace` and `-d` and `--debug` are synonymous and `-d` already implies `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

I re-installed java and the problem is solved.